# "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am currently trying to write my first JS module, and simply have the following

**dist/script.js**

```
// Import classes
import { ScrollTrigger } from './lib/scroll-trigger.js';
```

**dist/lib/scroll-trigger.js**

```
export class ScrollTrigger {
  constructor() {
    console.log("working");
  }

  /**
   * Run the logic
   */
  init() {

  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

// Process and minify SCSS to CSS
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

// Compress scripts
gulp.task('compress', function() {
  gulp.src('scripts/**/*.js')
  .pipe(babel())
  .pipe(minify({
    ext:{
      src:'-debug.js',
      min:'.js'
    },
    exclude: ['tasks'],
    ignoreFiles: ['.combo.js', '-min.js']
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('default',function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss',['styles']);
    gulp.watch('scripts/**/*.js',['compress']);
});
```

However when running, I receive "import not defined", and when running through the BabelJS gulp task I have setup, I receive "require is not defined".

I feel I'm missing something completely obvious here, but am at a loss!

Comment: Does `ScrollTriger` exports from 'scroll-trigger.js'?

Comment: Can you provide your gulp tasks?

Comment: Babel compiles individual files from ES6 to ES5, but if you want modules to work in a browser you still need something like Webpack to bundle up all the module files into something that a browser will understand. Babel's usual output would be for if your code is running in Node.

Comment: @SerejaNagin Gulpfile added.

Comment: @MikhailKatrin Please could you clarify?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm already using Gulp as mentioned, and have followed the instructions for Gulp on the Babel website.

Comment: Right, and that won't work. You need a bundler, otherwise you're just concatenating files without actually connecting up the imports and exports of your files.

Comment: @loganfsmyth ok thanks for the info. I haven't actually used Webpack yet and thought it was similar to Grunt/Gulp. Will take a look.